# using setState inside useEffect in a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("useeffect");
  let image = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    image = [...image, "https://source.unsplash.com/random"];
  }
  setImages(image);

}, []);
```

[image: output]

```
useEffect(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setImages((images) => [...images, "https://source.unsplash.com/random"]);
  }
}, []);
```

---

[image: output]

why there is difference in output not able to understand.

Comment: Because in React 18 strict mode, the `useEffect` is called twice. If you set the same state twice (like you do in the 1st example) - you get result 1, and if you add to the current state (2nd example), you get double the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know **React 18** now has *Strict.Mode* mount, unmount, and remount components thus **useEffect is called twice** and in your first example you set your state once and then you **re-write** it again on second render. However in your 2nd example you are updating your state, and in second render you are updating it with new images, but you are not deleting previous images, so they are all present. Remember, this only happens in development mode when Strict.Mode is applied in your index.js.